# How do I rewrite this javascript in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript that generates some random string, that I want to rewrite in jQuery:

```
function randomString() {
        var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()_+";
        var string_length = 8;
        var randomStr = '';
        for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randomStr += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
        }
        document.getElementById('randomfield').innerHTML=randomStr;
    }
```

Is it possible to wrap it in something like this  $('.classname').click(function()

Comment: Why.....................?

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: jquery doesn't have any string manipulation, therefore the only line that would change is second to last.

Comment: [DON'T DO IT-](http://vanilla-js.com/). Wait, you can't. jQuery is for DOM manipulation, this is pure data stuff.

Comment: @KevinB Which could be a `return` statement instead of causing side-effects.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol `$('#randomfield').html(randomStr);` :)

Comment: Because I want to wrap it in something like this:  $('.id').click(function()

Comment: Wrap it right on in there. You can still use javascript inside jQuery functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on you rcomment, you want to use the reference of what is clicked. So call the function

```
$('.className').click(randomString);
```

It will set this to the object, so inside of randomString you can use `$(this).text(randomStr);`

---

```
    function randomString() {
        var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()_+";
        var string_length = 8;
        var randomStr = '';
        for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randomStr += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
        }
        $(this).text(randomStr);
    }


    $('.className').click(randomString);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I replaced $(this) with $('.key') which is the div I want the string to appear in, and it worked well.

Answer (score 2):

First things first: jQuery is javascript, so no need to rewrite. Why you should rewrite your function is to make it more reusable:

```
// Instead of apply a random string value to a specific DOM element
// .. create a random string and return its value

function getRandomString() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()_+";
    var string_length = 8;
    var randomStr = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomStr += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    return randomStr;
}

// Quite useful, because we can now use it whenever we want. 
// For example use it within a click handler function:

$('#button').on('click', function () {
    $('#randomfield').text(getRandomString());        
});
```

Comment: OP is not asking that apparently,  read his question.

Comment: That doesn't make it less useful; I've rewritten the code (and you can immediately see why the rewrite is useful)

Comment: I reread the question and think that this is a valid answer. For inexperienced users a little explanation could make it easier to understand. Nonetheless +1 from me.

Comment: He changed the answer now

Answer (score 0):

Widget factory allows you to add jQuery functions; it would look something like this.

```
$.widget('nt.randomString', {
     var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()_+";
        var string_length = 8;
        var randomStr = '';
        for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randomStr += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
});
$("#randomfield").randomString.text()
```

Here is a tutorial on using widget factory http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/an-in-depth-review-of-jquerys-widget-factory/

Comment: that doesn't look like valid javascript... something's missing.

Comment: You can also build your own chaining API http://blog.buymeasoda.com/creating-a-jquery-like-chaining-api/